# Add incremental values in a single insert statement

Tags: sql-server

The query below is not my actual query but a minimized version of it, as I cannot post the original one. However this explains what I want to do exactly:

```
Insert into TableA (BirthdateA, NameA)
Select BirthdateB,  (case when NameB is not null then NameB else "Desired Value" End) 
From TableB
```

"Desired Value" should be a dummy name in addition to an incremental value, for example "Dummy Name 1", "Dummy Name 2"
So the final result would look like

```
TableB.Name     TableA.Name
John Smith       John Smith
Null             Dummy Name 1
Adam James       Adam James
John K.          John K.
Null             Dummy Name 2
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT 
    BirthDateB,
    CASE WHEN NameB IS NULL THEN 
        ('Dummy Name ' + CAST(DT.rn As varchar(10))) 
    ELSE NameB END As NameA
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NameB ORDER BY NameB) As rn
    FROM 
        TableB) DT
```

> **Note :**
>   I use `ORDER BY NameB` because I don't know what is your PK, you can change `NameB` to your PK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I got one question, if i did it this way, this means that the number after Dummy Name will not be incremental (+1) but will be equivalent to that row's number (ie. Dummy Name 3 followed by Dummy Name 5 possibly) is that true ?

Comment: @user4612290 When you use `PARTITION BY NameB` it will not be the row number it will be the rank based on `NameB` ;).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (No INT IDENTITY(1,1), BirthDate varchar(100), Name varchar(250))

INSERT INTO #Temp (Name) 
SELECT BirthDate, 'Dummy Name'
FROM TableB
WHERE Name IS NULL


SELECT BirthDate, Name
FROM
FROM TableB
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT BirthDate, Name + CAST(No VARCHAR(100))
FROM
FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I bind each row of the Temp table to their data from TableB ? Each Name in Temp has a Birthdate in TableB

Comment: This would work with me too, I chose the other answer however as it will provide it with the least steps. Thanks a lot